# force non https version of website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After installing ssl and making all pages https by using htaccess I realised that my website actually cannot run with https because it has a lot of embeded code with http protocol which cannot be changed to https or removed, but simply removing the rewrite rule which forces https does not work because google has indexed all pages with https, so now most part of the google search traffic goes to https version of website and they see mixed content error.
I tried to implement examples that I found in forums but when I apply this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

the browser always redirects from https://example.com/anypage to http://example.com/index.php

Here is the full code from .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

#Force non-www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: You should expect that within the next couple of years browsers will move towards *requiring* HTTPS. I know you say the HTTP-only assets "cannot be changed to https or removed", but chances are you're going to have to at some point.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, I understand that I will have to... but not now. Now I want my visitors to see the content and not errors)) I hope there is a way to fix this issue

Comment: Just move `# Handle Front Controller...` rule below all other rules.